# Вывести топ игроков

Tags: php, mysql

помогите, есть код:

```
if(isset($_GET['dolar'])){
    echo "< p style='padding:4px;margin:0;font-weight:bold;background:#cc0000;text-align:left;'>Топ богатых</p>";
    $dol = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY `money` DESC LIMIT 10") or die(mysql_error());
    $dolar_row = mysql_fetch_array($dol);
    do{
        $idd = $dolar_row['id'];
            printf(
"<table class='wdt screentop'>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <center>< img src='%s' alt='%s' width='210' align='left'/><br /><br />
        < font color='#ff0000'>< b> место</b></font></br>
        %s <br/>
        < img src='img/money.png' alt='speed' /> < font color='#23b900'><b>%s</b></font>
        </center>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>",
                $dolar_row['car'],
                $dolar_row['carname'],
                $idd,
                $dolar_row['nick'],
                $dolar_row['money']
            );
    } while( $dolar_row = mysql_fetch_array($dol));
}
```

нужно вывести места напрмер у кого много баксов 1 место 2 место 3 место, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cчетчик в переменную (например $place) положите и делайте его $place++ в теле цикла, выводите в нужную вам колонку.
или можно так:

```
SELECT @place:=@place+1 as place,users.* FROM users,(SELECT @place:=0) p ORDER BY `money` DESC LIMIT 10 "
```

---

[depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

```
Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
функции:
```

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: спасибо огромное